# SeekBar minHeight and maxHeight by code

Tags: android, seekbar

Does anybody know how to set the minimum and the maximum `SeekBar`'s height by code? I want to reproduce the same behavior as the following XML's excerpt:

```
<SeekBar android:minHeight="6dip"
         android:maxHeight="6dip" ... />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if there is a code for it. I achieve this creating an xml with the maximum height and other attributes and inflating the seekBar in its definition:

In XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_player_seekbar_background"
        android:paddingTop="10px" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px" 
        android:thumb="@drawable/bt_do_player" 
        android:paddingLeft="30px" 
        android:paddingRight="30px" 
        android:minHeight="6dip"
        android:maxHeight="6dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

And in the java code:

```
volumeSeekBarPL = (SeekBar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_seek_bar, null);
```